# How to check double brackets in android?

Tags: android, json

I'm a beginner in android development, and I get an empty json or this json: `[]`

to show a relevant message. For example:
`if json='[]'` then show message `'ok'`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a `JSONObject` and check its length, if it's zero then you can show a message in something like a `Toast`.

```
String txt = "[]";
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(txt);

    if (json.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ok!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you could simply process the JSON String before you do anything with it. Like:

```
String txt = "[]";

if (txt.isEmpty() || txt.equals("[]")) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Ok!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can read more about `JSONObject` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), and about `Toast` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Answer (score 2):

At first deJson it to proper object (probably an Array) by `gson.fromJson(...)` method and then check if its length is 0 or not

Example:

```
String strJson = "[]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] arr = gson.fromJson(strJson, String[].class);
```

Comment: Gson is a library by Google which can convert Java objects to its JSON representation and vice versa. See https://github.com/google/gson/tree/master/gson.